# Ios FBSDKGameRequestDialog send cancel method event

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api

```
FBSDKGameRequestContent *content = [[FBSDKGameRequestContent alloc]init];
content.message = @"Great FB";
content.title = @"Invite Friends";
FBSDKGameRequestDialog *gameDialog = [[FBSDKGameRequestDialog alloc]init];
gameDialog.content = content;
gameDialog.frictionlessRequestsEnabled = YES;
gameDialog.delegate = self;
if ([gameDialog canShow]) {
   [gameDialog show];
}
```

I am using the above code for showing FBFriends. The dialog is opened, but I want to perform some of my custom functionality after user hits send/cancel.
How should I do it?

Answer (score 1):

You're doing:

```
gameDialog.delegate = self;
```

So, why don't you use the delegate methods (`FBSDKGameRequestDialogDelegate`): `gameRequestDialogDidCancel:` and
`gameRequestDialog:didCompleteWithResults:` to know if user has cancelled of sent its invitation?

[Source](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ios/current/protocol/FBSDKGameRequestDialogDelegate/)

In your YourCurrentClass.h:

```
@interface YourCurrentClass : NSObject < FBSDKGameRequestDialogDelegate >
```

In your YourCurrentClass.m:

```
- (void)gameRequestDialog:(FBSDKGameRequestDialog *)gameRequestDialog
didCompleteWithResults:(NSDictionary *)results
{
    //User has done something.
    //Check "results" and do something.
}

- (void)gameRequestDialogDidCancel:(FBSDKGameRequestDialog *)gameRequestDialog
{
    //User has cancelled
    //Do somathing
}

- (void)gameRequestDialog:(FBSDKGameRequestDialog *)gameRequestDialog
didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    //An error happened
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    //Do something
}
```

Comment: Thnkx for ur answer. can u give a sample of code? i have tried.. but i stucked... :(

Comment: It's like any Delegate method (UITableView have a few, UICollection too, etc.) What's your issue? I don't use FaceBook API, but this should be working. Did you go to the Source I linked? There is the doc on theses method there.

Comment: I have tried to use delegate method... but its not working... i have n't work on FB Api...

Comment: What do you mean not working? What's your new code? Aren't the method called?

Comment: On my answer. I edited it. If you had error, which one?

Comment: If this works, please accept answer, in order to help people if someone has the same issue.